# Graphical representation of reductive powers of NaBH4 and LiAlH4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, reactivity

I don't know whether this is a valid question, I will delete it if it is inappropriate.

I am looking for a graphical representation of the reductive powers of $\ce{NaBH4}$ and $\ce{LiAlH4}$. Such as this

[image]

but then including acyl chlorides and the other important organic functional groups.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38747/why-nabh4-does-not-reduce-carboxylic-acid-while-lialh4-does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perhaps more than what you are asking for, but the textbook by Clayden et al.<sup>1</sup> has a good overview of reducing agents and their substrates:

[image: Summary of reducing agents for carbonyl groups]

#### Reference

(1) Clayden, J.; Greeves, N.; Warren, S. *Organic Chemistry*, 2nd ed.; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2012; p 534.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{LiAlH4}$ reduces all carbonyl compounds to their respective reduced forms,mostly alcohols. Now since you insisted on a graphic, This was what I could
make up within the short period.
[image]